# Wave equation in three space dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Suppose that $u$ satisfies the Wave Equation in $R^{1+3}$ with initial conditions
$u(0, x) = 0$, $u_t(0, x) = g(x)$
for $x \in R^3$ and $g \in L^p(R^3)$.
Show that $u(t, ·) \in L^p(R^3)$ for all $t$ and
$||u(t, ·)||_p ≤ || g ||_p|t|$.

I missed the last few lectures in this class and would like to know what the dot in $u(t, ·)$ means.

Any pointers on doing the problem would be great, thanks.

I used Kirchoff's formula to write $u$ as $u(t,x)=\frac{1}{4\pi t^2}\int_{\partial S}tg(y)dS$. I then took the norm of it but it's not really giving me something usable, just that expression within the norm expression. I know I should use Minkowski's inequality but I can't get it in a usable form. Any tips?

Comment: The dot just means the $x$ variable.  As you can see, the estimate only depends on the $t$ slice.

Comment: Hint: Use Kirchhoff's formula to get a representation of $u$.

Comment: I was actually doing that when I saw your message. I have a representation for $u$ but not sure what to do with it. @Jose27

Comment: Now take $L^p$ norms of the representation and use [Minkowski's integral inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski.27s_integral_inequality) on the RHS.